# How to get files from another branch into my current branch?

Tags: git

here is a situation:

I was on `branch1` and pushed my changes. Then I did second task on `branch2` and pushed it too. After, I switched again to a `branch1` and added some code into it, pushed again. Now I'm in `branch2` again and do not have last changes which was made in `branch1`.

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using git bash or some IDE with git support? What you want is a "merge". Just a second ... I'll find a link.

Comment: I'm using git bash

Comment: There you go: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I frequently use this to pull from master into a working branch.
`git pull origin branch1`

Answer (score 1):

Try mergin branches.

`git pull --all`

`git checkout branch2`

`git merge branch1`

You might need to resolve some merge conflicts